# What is entire function and how can I show that it is not continuous?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Given the function
$$
f(z)=\frac{e^{z}}{z^{2}-z-2}
$$
Is this function entire? If not, for what value(s) of $z$, will this function cease to be analytic?

I am struggling to understand this question. How can I convert that equation to $A+iB$ form? How can I show that it is discontinuous?

Comment: Where is this function not defined at? Where are you dividing by zero?

Comment: entire functions are functions that are holomorphic on the whole space $\mathbb C$.

Comment: As a general rule, in complex analysis it is a bad idea to try to express things in "$A+iB$ form". That almost always makes things more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder in what context you came across this problem.

Entire functions are differentiable everywhere in the complex plane and therefore are continuous everywhere in the plane.

Functions are not considered holomorphic (i.e. not differentiable in some open neighborhood) at points where their value is $\infty.$

The function $z\mapsto e^z$ is nowhere $0.$ But the denominator $z^2-z-2$ is $0$ at two points in the plane (and both of those are real numbers). At a point where the numerator is a holomorphic function and is not $0$ and the denominator is a holomorphic function and is $0,$ the value of the function is $\infty.$ If such points exist, the function is not entire.

There is seldom any reason to look at anything in $\text{“}A+iB\text{ form”}$ in this subject.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Check when $z^2 - z - 2=0$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$